# Can't get out of minibuffer completion

Tags: debugging, completion, minibuffer

Since upgrading from v. 24 to v. 25 [OSX 10.11.6] I find myself frequently fighting with minibuffer completion, as typing a tab after doing switch-to-buffer. ^G just beeps, and the completions redisplay. The only way I know to exit the minibuffer in this situation is to pick one of the completions, either with the mouse or by navigating with keys.  I have a pretty simple setup with respect to switch-buffer. I don't think I  use any buffer libraries that would affect his, and have not changed buffer handling for several versions. Any suggestions about what is causing this and how I can get out of minibuffer completion without choosing one of the completions?

Comment: Does your problem persist when you try running Emacs without your configuration (`emacs -q`?) If it doesn't, then your config is the problem. I couldn't reproduce your issue in Emacs 25 without configuration.

Comment: What @DoMiNeLa10 said. If you see the same thing when starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` then provide a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem. If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Answer (score 9):

Is it possible there is an active recursive edit in the completion minibuffer? <kbd>C-]</kbd> by default is `abort-recursive-edit`. Alternatively `keyboard-escape-quit` or <kbd>ESC ESC ESC</kbd> might help?

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same thing, but I knew that for me it had started sometime *after* I'd upgraded to and had been using Emacs 25.  In my case, the problem turned out to be my recent addition of the following to my `~/.emacs` file:

```
(set-frame-parameter nil 'unsplittable t)
```

The above was one of several things I had used to try to undo some *other* behavior changes that Emacs 25 brought in.  In this case, it wasn't the right thing to try.

This also might explain why I didn't seem to get stuck in the minibuffer when I was running with my full `~/.emacs` configuration, yet in `--no-window-system (-nw)` mode.  There, as I understand it, frames aren't even a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! This has been making me crazy for a long time. Today I spent some more time searching and exploring. I stumbled on the answer after doing ^H-m when in the minibuffer. The fourth keybinding listed is "q", quit-window. Typing q when completions are displayed closes the completion buffer and returns to the minibuffer, where ^G aborts normally.

I don't understand why it was so difficult for me to figure this out, or why there aren't a lot of people complaining about this.